# Auto-Rezisable viewpager with scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to have and activity to display some statistics. In this activity I want to input the beginning and the end date and with them, show some statistics and some graphics. To do so I created an activity in which the top where I chose the input dates if fixed. Then I have a TablLayout and a viewpager in which I show the statistics and the graphics. 
All these seems to work fine and this is the [result on the activity](http://s27.postimg.org/uf5r2dvlv/activity_example.jpg).However, my problem is twofold :
On one hand,  I can’t resize the viewpager automatically to fit the activity heigh and show the contents of the fragments properly. If I set the viewpager to wrap_content and the fragments to match_parent, there is nothing shown. However, if I forche the viewpager height manually, then I am able to see the viewpager working ( but not adjusting the activity height properly ). 
On the other hand, when I am able to see the viewpager content, I just want to scroll the contents of the viewpager. However, if I insert a scrollview or a nestedscrollview the entire activity scrolls which is what I don’t want. 
This is the layout of the activity where I want to put all these together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.app.asaak.activities.InformesActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_informes">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
        <!-- ================ LAYOUT BOTONES ================ -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <!-- ================ BOTON DESDE ================ -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/informes_boton_desde"
                android:text="DESDE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <!-- ================ BOTON HASTA ================ -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/informes_boton_hasta"
                android:text="HASTA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- ================ LAYOUT TEXT ================ -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <!-- ================ TEXTVIEW DESDE ================ -->
            <com.app.asaak.textViews.CTextViewName
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dd/mm/aaaa"
                android:id="@+id/informes_text_desde"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
            <!-- ================ TEXTVIEW HASTA ================ -->
            <com.app.asaak.textViews.CTextViewName
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dd/mm/aaaa"
                android:id="@+id/informes_text_hasta"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--        VIEWPAGER               -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_informes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

            <!--  VIEWPAGER -->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_informes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabs_informes"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is an example of the two contents I want to put on tab informes or tab graphics.

tab graphics:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- GRAPHICS AND INFORMATION HERE THAT DOESN'T FIT THE ACTIVITY SO MUST BE SCROLLED -->

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can se viewpager height is forced, if I put wrap_content I can't see anything.

How can I do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.app.asaak.activities.InformesActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_informes">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
        <!-- ================ LAYOUT BOTONES ================ -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <!-- ================ BOTON DESDE ================ -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/informes_boton_desde"
                android:text="DESDE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <!-- ================ BOTON HASTA ================ -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/informes_boton_hasta"
                android:text="HASTA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- ================ LAYOUT TEXT ================ -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <!-- ================ TEXTVIEW DESDE ================ -->
            <com.app.asaak.textViews.CTextViewName
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dd/mm/aaaa"
                android:id="@+id/informes_text_desde"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
            <!-- ================ TEXTVIEW HASTA ================ -->
            <com.app.asaak.textViews.CTextViewName
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="dd/mm/aaaa"
                android:id="@+id/informes_text_hasta"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--        VIEWPAGER               -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_informes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

            <!--  VIEWPAGER -->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_informes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabs_informes"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changed outer `linearlayout` height to `match_parent`.
Changed `TabLayout` height to 0dp and weight 1.
Changed `ViewPager` height to `match_parent`.

Comment: Sorry, not working :/ yet, I don't understand the weight=1 in here.

Comment: Any changes in the layout?

Comment: I did the changes suggested, but now when I press the tabs nothing shows on the viewpager

Comment: Button height is set to `match_parent`. Change to `wrap_content` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Tablayout and viewpager to this:

```
<!--        TABLAYOUT               -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_informes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


            <!--  VIEWPAGER -->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_informes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabs_informes"
                />
```

and each tab_layout with width and height = match_parent I am able to see now the tabs filled. However, I still have the problem I am not able to scroll the contents of the viewpager so I can only see a part of the full content.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i ended up in same situation. I got a work around.

It can be achieved by extending ViewPager class. create a class like

```
public class WrapContentHeightViewPager extends ViewPager {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context the context
     */
    public WrapContentHeightViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context the context
     * @param attrs   the attribute set
     */
    public WrapContentHeightViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // find the first child view
        View view = getChildAt(0);
        if (view != null) {
            // measure the first child view with the specified measure spec
            view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, view));
    }

    /**
     * Determines the height of this view
     *
     * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @param view        the base view with already measured height
     * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec, View view) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // set the height from the base view if available
            if (view != null) {
                result = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this class ensure that the height of the view pager is same as the view inside.

after creating class just replace ViewPager in the layout with the custom view pager you created. like :

```
<com.your.packagename.WrapContentHeightViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_informes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tabs_informes"
                />
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: Ok I did changes you suggested but still content does not fit in my Galaxy SIV so I need to scroll the contents of the viewpager up and down but I can't. I tried to enable nestedscrollling but nothing changes.

Comment: What was your layout height of view pager in layout? @asaak

Comment: I tried wrap_contet and works with first fragment, not with the second one. Second fragment shows nothing while I was able to see boths graphs before

Comment: Oh your pages height is dynamic?

Comment: BTW I was using viewpagerstateadapter

Comment: Nop both of my tabs has a static height, in case of statistics it has always same lines of data to show and in the case of graphics there are always 2 graphics

Comment: Oh it is working fine for me.  Could u please try using viewpagerstateadapter instead of viepageradapter?

Answer (score 0):

After try the solution suggested, I added a Scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!--  VIEWPAGER -->
                <com.app.asaak.support.HeightAdaptableViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager_informes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tabs_informes"
                    />

                </ScrollView>
```

Now its working for the first tab, but when I change to the second tab ( in which I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:id="@+id/grafico_turnos" />

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/grafico_reservas" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't see them, even if I scroll up and down on its tab. Looks like graphs are somewhere but I can't reach them scrolling, because I am not able to scroll enough.

Another curious thing is that even if I insert margin inside my fragment, the bottom margin is not respected when I show the statistics margin so the margin at the end of the tab is not shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out it was easier than I thought! After a lot of trying and with your help I found a solution. Just use a regular viewPager and make height = match_parent. Then in both tab's layout insert a Scrollview with height = wrap_content and thats it, working as expected!

Thank you guys!